# How to change and place search bar icon?

Tags: html, css

I made a custom google search bar and i changed the search button icon with my own.

CSS :

```
.cse input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button {
background: url(searchicon.png)no-repeat !important;}
```

And the custom search bar :

```
<script>
(function() {
var cx = '006844625513047305011:czguvh5_mrc';
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/KeZWV/

How can i make my icon center in the bordered area? I used the same icon but changed the color in paint.

And how could i change the "Google custom search" in the text box?

Comment: i don't think you are allowed to do that

Comment: Propably but still wonder how to

Comment: I dont think changing the icon is a big problem but changing the "Google custom search"..

Answer (score 0):

If you can fix the size of the .gsc-input element, you can do something like this (CSS):

```
.cse input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button {
    background: url(searchicon.png)no-repeat !important;
}
.gsc-input {
    width: 1000px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.gsc-search-button {
    position: relative;
    right: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KeZWV/7/

Its a hot-fix, play with right and width vales... is not a very elegant, but it could work.

PS: I know its very crappy code, but just for give an idea.